# Linux: What programs are accessing the Internet?

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

So, I am starting to worry a little that something or someone is hacked into my Linux Laptop. I have installed a network Gnome Extension that displays size of bytes going up and down on my Internet connection. My laptop seems to be talking to some program on the internet I don't even know what it could be talking to. There is always some bytes (10 - 50kb every 4 seconds) on the average being received and transmitted. This happens even when I got no applications running on the system like FireFox.

Thinking that my laptop has been hacked, I completely reinstalled my Linux OS and still it is showing that there is always some bytes going up and down the Internet.

I did do the netstat -all command on the terminal but that doesn't really show much and it looks way to cryptic. I want some program like Etherape program. Etherape is too confusing to use.

What do you suggest? I need to know what program is transmitting and receiving bytes on my Linux system.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
netstat -an
```

you will see which ports that are in a connection at the moment.

If you want to see which process that is connected to a certain, port 80 in this case, you can use

```
lsof -i tcp:80
```

Well, you need to be root, of course.

Comment: yts1.yql.vip.bf1.yahoo.com this is what was shown when I had all the other internet accessing programs on my linux system off.

Answer (score 1):

this connection is made by the cinnamon panel weather applet, according to what i was able to find about it, in case anyone else comes here wondering what it is.  It's not anything malicious, and in fact, you probably had to choose to add it from cinnamon's downloadable applets.  (Cinnamon is a desktop environment, if you are on mint it's likely your default.)